# CircleCI - Modify PATH environment variable windows executor job

Tags: environment-variables, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am trying to write a windows job in Circle CI and figure out a way to modify/append to PATH env variable. I need it to point to some installation directories that I import during this executor job.

I am referring to this link: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/

However, it seems to have examples only for Linux images. Does anyone have an idea how to modify or append PATH env variables in windows executor job?

I setup the the executor with powershell.exe as demonstrated here https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/hello-world-windows/.

Comment: have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the Windows machine executor to use PowerShell, for example like:

```
executors:
  windows:
    machine:
      image: "windows-server-2022-gui:2023.06.1"
      shell: "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass"
```

Then you can use PowerShell in a step like this early in your job to modify PATH:

```
New-Item $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts -Force                                                                                                                          
Add-Content -Path $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts -Value '$env:PATH = "xyz;$env:PATH"'
```

Just as with bash, CircleCI gives each step its own shell environment so the more straightforward `$env:PATH = ...` will only affect whatever step you add it to.

The approach here is similar to the idea of `BASH_ENV` - generate some shell code to run at the start of each step to customize the shell environment.

The other thing to pay attention to is the way you specify the string for `-Value`.  Be aware of the PowerShell rules for substitution in different contexts (eg single-quoted string vs double-quoted string).

For example, I wanted to add a non-default Python "Scripts" directory to PATH so:

```
$q = py -<<parameters.pythonVersion>> -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('scripts'))"

New-Item $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts -Force

Add-Content -Path $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts -Value "`$env:PATH = `"$q;`$env:PATH`"
```

Here I use double-quoted strings to allow interpolation of `q` but then use backtick to escape `$` on `env:PATH` so it won't be interpolated *here* (so it can be interpolated later, to respect any other changes that might be made meanwhile).